# Adding trailing zeros to row values to make sure there are 10 digits

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

If i have a data frame where max digits in each row is 10 but some IDs are less than 10 because the trailing zeros have been cut off, how do I add trailing zeros in python to make sure there are 10 digits in each row.

```
ID
1234567689
123456768
12345676
```

```
ID
1234567689
1234567680
1234567600
```

Comment: What is the `dtype` of that column?

Comment: Why have the trailing zeroes been cut off?

Comment: The dtype is string

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `str.pad()` which I believe works perfect for this scenario:

```
df['ID'] = df['ID'].str.pad(width=10,side='right',fillchar='0')
```

In case the `dtype` of the column is not string, then you can first convert it:

```
df['ID'] = df['ID'].astype(str).str.pad(width=10,side='right',fillchar='0')
```

Output:

```
           ID
0  1234567689
1  1234567680
2  1234567600
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to use, [`Series.str.ljust`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.ljust.html#pandas.Series.str.ljust):

```
df['ID'] = df['ID'].str.ljust(width=10, fillchar='0')
```

Result:

```
           ID
0  1234567689
1  1234567680
2  1234567600
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ljust` for this:

```
df = df['ID'].astype(str).str.ljust(10, '0')
print(df)

0    1234567689
1    1234567680
2    1234567600
```

Answer (score 1):

I think f-formatting can do that

```py
X = [1234567689, 12345, 123,]
print([f'{item:0<9}' for item in X])
```

This only works with Python 3.6+. The idea is to get the value and left pad 9 zeros. In Pandas you can do, the following to maintain your field as numeric

```py
df['ID'] = df['ID'].apply(lambda x: f'{x:0<9'}).astype(int)
```