# How to slice the Time in Hours and Minutes in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to split the Time column from my dataset. The Time column has a value like this '2324' instead of '23:24'. I have used this command df['MINUTES']=df['MINUTES'].str[1:3]. but it didn't work accurately, since the time column is based on 24 hours. So '2324' showing as '23:32' which is incorrect.How do I split them into proper way. Please be gentle I am just starting out in Python/DA field.

Thanks in advance!
Anil

Comment: Could you please provide some example of your input data and what do you expect as output please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure where did the issue arise, since having 24 hrs time shouldn't affect the script. Here's an example that seems to match the expected output:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Example':['1242','1342','1532','1643','1758','1821','1902','0004','2324']})
df['Hour'] = df['Example'].str[:2]
df['Minute'] = df['Example'].str[2:]
df['Time'] = df['Example'].str[:2] + ":" + df['Example'].str[2:]
```

This generates the following output:

```
  Example Hour Minute   Time
0    1242   12     42  12:42
1    1342   13     42  13:42
2    1532   15     32  15:32
3    1643   16     43  16:43
4    1758   17     58  17:58
5    1821   18     21  18:21
6    1902   19     02  19:02
7    0004   00     04  00:04
8    2324   23     24  23:24
```

Comment: Thats great, Celius. Sorry I should have mentioned that the numbers are from 1 to 9 have 3 digits instead of 4. For example '236' or '720' that was causing an issue. However, your solution works fine as well. Plus, I have appended the zero if the length is less than 4 and then sliced the way you showed. This is the command I used. 
df['NewTime'].map(lambda x: f'{x:0>4}')

Is there any other easier command that could work, as I found it hard to understand the lambda concept. but again, worked for me :)
Thanks again!

Comment: Hello @Anil, I'm glad it worked. Feel free to accept the answer if your question is solved. Regarding adding the extra 0, you could use `pad` which is a panda's function, you can check my answer here, which seems to providea solution for your situation, in an easier way than lambda: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62661556/adding-trailing-zeros-to-row-values-to-make-sure-there-are-10-digits/62661622#62661622 feel free to leave a comment if you have further questions!

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you can do:

```
df['MINUTES'].replace(['(?<=\d\d)(?=\d\d)'], ':', regex=True, inplace=True)
```

---

---

We are basically telling python to inset a colon `':'` in this gap: `'(?<=\d\d)(?=\d\d)'`, which is between two digits on each side.

Lets test it:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'MINUTES':['1234',
                              '7654',
                              '8766']})

df['MINUTES'].replace(['(?<=\d\d)(?=\d\d)'], ':',
                      regex=True,
                      inplace=True)

print(df)
```

Output:

```
  MINUTES
0   12:34
1   76:54
2   87:66
```